# How can I find all the records over multiple datasets in a postgresql database with a null value in the geom column?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a postgresql database with multiple datasets some of which have a column named geom that holds the geometry.  I want to search the whole database looking at just those datasets with this field name (i.e. with geometry) to find all the records that have no geometry.

I can get a list of all the datasets within the database with a column named geom (i.e. with geometry) using the following:-
SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE column_name = 'geom';

But am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: You'll need to dynamically construct and execute your query from the information_schema results.

Comment: Thanks, for the reply, I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: [first google result](https://hub.packtpub.com/how-to-implement-dynamic-sql-in-postgresql-10/)